# Providing the same function to several React Native components not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

I am using React Native to code a very simple database app where users can add their own characters and view them later on.

My issue is as follows.

A part of adding a character is setting their abilities, this is done via React Native **Tags** imported from Ant Mobile Design.

Below is How the tags are displayed in the application.

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
  <Tag onChange={() => this.handleAbility('Hell')} style={{ marginRight: 7 }}> Hell </Tag>
  {this.state.abilities.map(function (ability) {
  return <Tag onChange={() =>this.handleAbility(ability.label)} style={{ marginRight: 7 }}> {ability.label} </Tag>
  })}
</ScrollView>
```

and this is the code for the handleAbility function.

```
handleAbility = (label) => {
let character = Object.assign({}, this.state.character);
if (character.abilities.indexOf(label) == -1) {
character.abilities.push(label);
this.setState({ character });
} else {
character.abilities.pop();
this.setState({ character });
}
}
```

When I press on the tag I manually wrote with the "Hell" tag, the function is triggered successfully, and the ability "Hell" is pushed to the character's attributes in the app's state. **However**, when I press on any of the other tags that were produced via the map function the following error occurs. I tried several methods to fix this to no avail, any help is appreciated!

[image: TypeError]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try changing this line:

`{this.state.abilities.map(function (ability) {`

to an arrow function, like this:

`{this.state.abilities.map(ability => {`

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot!
Worked like a charm and I instantly got the logic behind it and why it wasn't working in the first place...

Comment: Good to hear! :)